# Using setup.py with Python Click - what should I commit to git?

Tags: python, git, setuptools, python-click, requirements.txt

I'm using Python Click to build a command-line interface, with setuptools as per https://click.palletsprojects.com/en/7.x/setuptools/

After running

```
$ virtualenv venv
$ . venv/bin/activate
$ pip install --editable .
```

When I run `pip freeze` I see a line:

```
-e git+ssh://git@bitbucket.mydomain:8203/xyz/mycli.git@9ef8bc6cb7cfc1bfd57bda6e3a376400a4ce055d#egg=
```

Should I be committing this to the requirements.txt in git?  If so, how do I get around the problem where the commit hash is inevitably 1 behind the version I eventually push?

Or, do I need to instruct my colleagues to run:

```
pip install --editable .
```

every time they pull the latest code from master branch?

Comment: I've always instructed my colleagues to run `pip install --editable .` instead of committing that to my requirements.txt. Haven't had any issues with that so far, and I would find it weird if that was part of your requirements